# SonarQube cannot blame file

Tags: jenkins, svn, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

During a code check with SonarQube, I am getting this sort of error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error when executing blame for file some/file/in/project/file.hpp
    at org.sonar.plugins.scm.svn.SvnBlameCommand.blame(SvnBlameCommand.java:85)
    at org.sonar.plugins.scm.svn.SvnBlameCommand.blame(SvnBlameCommand.java:58)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scm.ScmPublisher.publish(ScmPublisher.java:85)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.PublishPhaseExecutor.afterSensors(PublishPhaseExecutor.java:60)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseExecutor.java:90)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:180)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:121)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:288)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:283)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:261)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:121)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:48)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:84)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:121)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:121)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecuteTask(Batch.java:116)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:111)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:233)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedScanner.java:151)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.runAnalysis(Main.java:123)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:77)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E204899: Cannot delete file 'C:\Path\to\project\.svn\tmp\annotate.3.tmp\annotate.tmp'
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:70)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNFileUtil.deleteFile(SVNFileUtil.java:1342)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNFileUtil.deleteAll(SVNFileUtil.java:1314)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNFileUtil.deleteAll(SVNFileUtil.java:1305)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.remote.SvnRemoteAnnotate.run(SvnRemoteAnnotate.java:143)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.remote.SvnRemoteAnnotate.run(SvnRemoteAnnotate.java:30)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnOperationRunner.run(SvnOperationRunner.java:21)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.run(SvnOperationFactory.java:1235)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperation.run(SvnOperation.java:294)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNLogClient.doAnnotate(SVNLogClient.java:295)
    at org.sonar.plugins.scm.svn.SvnBlameCommand.blame(SvnBlameCommand.java:83)
    ... 31 more
```

**Some additional information**

- This project is checked out in a Jenkins job.
- No other project checked the same way have this sort of error.
- This project is a big project, so code checking takes several hours.
- I can blame this file in the error message (`some/file/in/project/file.hpp`) without problems with TortoiseSVN.
- I am using SonarQube 6.7.1 LTS
- SonarQube Plugin for SVN has this version 1.6.0.860
- `svn --version` gives me this output, so it seems up to date:

> ```
> svn, version 1.9.7 (r1800392)
>    compiled Aug  8 2017, 22:14:48 on x86-microsoft-windows
>
> Copyright (C) 2017 The Apache Software Foundation.
> This software consists of contributions made by many people;
> see the NOTICE file for more information.
> Subversion is open source software, see http://subversion.apache.org/
>
> The following repository access (RA) modules are available:
>
> * ra_svn : Module for accessing a repository using the svn network protocol.
>   - with Cyrus SASL authentication
>   - handles 'svn' scheme
> * ra_local : Module for accessing a repository on local disk.
>   - handles 'file' scheme
> * ra_serf : Module for accessing a repository via WebDAV protocol using serf.
>   - using serf 1.3.9 (compiled with 1.3.9)
>   - handles 'http' scheme
>   - handles 'https' scheme
>
> The following authentication credential caches are available:
>
> * Wincrypt cache in C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Subversion
> ```

**What I did**

- On the SonarQube Server, under Administration -> SCM, I added credentials.
- Before doing a SonarQube check, I am now doing a `svn upgrade`. The same error came up when I was not doing a `svn upgrade`.

Does anyone have an idea, what I can do to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you find any answers for this? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

In jenkins, "Execute SonarQube scanner " plugin, can you give scm disabled parameter ?
-Dsonar.scm.disabled=True

if that does not work, in sonarqube you must disable the scm parameter.
From Project -> General Settings -> SCM -> Disable the SCM Sensor. You must disable soarqube to look for source code.